# Setting navigation item titleview

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm playing around with a table bar controller and a navbar controller, and I'm having trouble setting navigation controller's titleView property. I thought it was fairly straight forward.

Code to set the titleView

```
   let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo 2"))
    titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 34)
    titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

    navController.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView
    navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white//UIColor.rgb(red: 38, green: 58, blue: 147)
```

Full controller

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .blue

        let homeController = HomeController()
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeController)

        navController.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "invoice-filled-50")
        navController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "invoice-filled-50")
        navController.tabBarItem.title = "Home"

        let redVC = UIViewController()
        redVC.view.backgroundColor = .red
        redVC.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money-box-50")
        redVC.tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "money-box-filled-50")
        redVC.tabBarItem.title = "Save"

        let greenVC = UIViewController()
        greenVC.view.backgroundColor = .green
        greenVC.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stocks-50")
        greenVC.tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "stocks-filled-50")
        greenVC.tabBarItem.title = "Invest"

        let orangeVC = UIViewController()
        orangeVC.view.backgroundColor = .orange
        orangeVC.tabBarItem.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notification-50")
        orangeVC.tabBarItem.selectedImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "notification-filled-50")
        orangeVC.tabBarItem.title = "Alerts"


        let titleImageView = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "Logo 2"))
        titleImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 34)
        titleImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

        navController.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView
        navController.navigationBar.barTintColor = .white//UIColor.rgb(red: 38, green: 58, blue: 147)

        tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 38, green: 58, blue: 147)
        viewControllers = [navController,redVC, greenVC, orangeVC]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify

```
navigationBar.topItem?.titleView = titleImageView
```

Not,

```
navController.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView
```

Comment: No, this is not correct. You should be setting the `titleView` of the `navigationItem` of a specific view controller. Then the navigation controller will show it when that view controller is the top view controller.

Comment: Noted, so say in RedVC you'd do `redVC.navigationItem.titleView = titleImageView`?